# Get raw post reply from Jsoup

Tags: java, http, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to post a form to a website, the reply is plain text, but the content type isn't known to Jsoup. Therefore I use ignoreContentType(true), so Jsoup won't throw an exception because of the unknown content type. However I can't figure out how to get the raw reply from Jsoup, the text contains some special characters, that Jsoup strips, also Jsoups adds a body and html tag - I don't need that, I just want the raw reply. How to get the raw reply? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Response#body()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html#body%28%29) for this. E.g.

```
String body = Jsoup.connect(url).execute().body();
```

Or if you're doing POST

```
String body = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Method.POST).data(data).execute().body();
```

Comment: Thank you, that would do the job, however I am wondering if it's really not possible to get the raw data from Jsoup. I am aware that it is a parser, but maybe there's still a method for it? ;-)

Comment: Thank you, but that's still not the raw data, besides the added body tags (not the real problem) some special characters are missing / removed by jsoup ):

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf,  are you sure you're using Response#body() as in BalusC's answer? That just pulls out the HTTP response body as a string. There is no parsing or any processing done. If you're seeing <body> tags I think that you're hitting a Document#body() method, which is different. Can you post your example code and point out where you're having issues?

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and solve it in two steps

1- gathering response

2- reading response as bytes and converting to string or parsing to anything you want (json,etc)

```
Response resp = jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).Method(Method.Post).execute();
String respStr = new String(resp.bodyAsBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `Response` object from `Connection`, and it contains the raw byte data. Ignore content type or it will fail on non-text data. If you use `body()` it may mangle the response using the default charset.

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).method(Method.GET);
Connection.Response response = conn.execute();
byte[] raw = response.bodyAsBytes();

// if you want...
Document parsed = response.parse();
```